# Upgrading OpenVPN - caveats?

Tags: openvpn

Im running OpenVPN 2.0.9 on RHEL5. I want to stay current with bug fixes and such so I've built 2.3.3.

Before I pull the proverbial trigger on this I'm wondering:

1. Will the existing clients reconnect? Will they need any sort of upgrade/ update?
2. Is this a one-way street? IE If there are issues, can I restart the 2.0.9 installation while I work out the details?
3. Any other gotchas to watch out for?

Comment: What did you discover in testing?

Comment: I'm not normally this reticent to upgrade software but there are hundreds of clients on this VPN. If I cut them off I have to visit each installation individually. .. so .. reluctant to test without knowing more about question #2.

Comment: Wait, don't you even _have_ a testing environment?! Not even a VM somewhere?

Comment: "A VM! Why yes.." (types frantically)" ..right here.. that test.. of course! Ha ha!" (more typing) (scratches head wondering how best to do this.. hangs head in shame .. prepares to delete posting...)

Comment: I have older clients connecting to my up-to-date OpenVPN server just fine.  But that is no guarantee things will work for you.  Testing is the only way to be sure.

Answer (score 0):

A good place to start is looking at the changelogs and notices by your distribution for the versions in between the current installation and the candidate. For example, Debian's latest testing packaged version is *2.3.2*-9 and it has [patches fixing 5 "bugs"](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/pkgreport.cgi?src=openvpn&include=tags:patch&exclude=tags:pending&pend-exc=done&repeatmerged=no).

After analysing the wealth of data available in bug reports on various distributions' trackers, you should then test your residual risk in the testing environment, as @MichaelHampton urges.

You can set up a quick and dirty testing environment with VirtualBox and Vagrant.